# How to delete from list?

Tags: python

Assuming I have the following list:

```
array1 = ['A', 'C', 'Desk']
```

and another array that contains:

```
array2 = [{'id': 'A', 'name': 'Greg'}, 
{'id': 'Desk', 'name': 'Will'},
{'id': 'E', 'name': 'Craig'},
{'id': 'G', 'name': 'Johnson'}]
```

What is a good way to remove items from the list? The following does not appear to work

```
for item in array2:
   if item['id'] in array1:
     array2.remove(item)
```

Comment: Doesn't remove take an index?

Comment: @SnakesandCoffee No, remove takes an item and removes the first occurrence of it in a list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could also use a list comprehension for this:

```
>>> array2 = [{'id': 'A', 'name': 'Greg'},
... {'id': 'Desk', 'name': 'Will'},
... {'id': 'E', 'name': 'Craig'},
... {'id': 'G', 'name': 'Johnson'}]
>>> array1 = ['A', 'C', 'Desk']
>>> filtered = [item for item in array2 if item['id'] not in array1]
>>> filtered
[{'id': 'E', 'name': 'Craig'}, {'id': 'G', 'name': 'Johnson'}]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use filter:

```
array2 = filter(lambda x: x['id'] not in array1, array2)
```

Comment: As a matter of fact @Paulo Scardine, this should be: `array2 = filter(lambda x: x['id'] not in array1, array2)` otherwise: `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'id'`

Comment: @PeterVaro: Good catch! I guess I'm doing too much javascript these days.

Comment: @PeterVaro Filter is not very pythonic. In fact, Guido wants it [removed from the language entirely](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196). The pythonic alternative is to use an if statement in a list comprehension.

Comment: It's worth noting that `filter` is a generator in Python 3, so you'd need to wrap this in a `list` call if you needed an actual list. If you are just going to iterate over it once, then it doesn't matter (unless something else mutates `array1` or `array2` before you do the iteration).

Comment: @Lanaru oh, I always thought that `filter` is a good tool:) Thanks anyway, although 99% of the time I use list comprehensions with if statements because I forget that there is a `filter()` function for this.. and it turned out, thanks to you, that it is more pythonic. Sweet.

Answer (score 3):

You're modifying a list while iterating over it. Instead iterate over a *copy* of the list

```
for item in array2[:]:  # [:] creates a copy
    ...
```

Comment: @Setsuna You are still removing from the original, just *iterating* over a copy.

Answer (score 2):

```
for item in array2:
   if item['id'] in array1:
     array2.remove(item)
```

A `for` loop keeps track of the index during the iterations.

**Iteration 1 : Index 0**

`item` is assigned `{'id': 'A', 'name': 'Greg'}` as it is at index 0.

As `'A'` as found in array so you removed this entry from the list.

Due to removal of that item all items to it's right actually shift one place to the left.

So, now `{'id': 'Desk', 'name': 'Will'}` is at index 0.

**Iteration 2 : Index value changed to 1**

This time `item` = `{'id': 'E', 'name': 'Craig'}` as this is at index 1.

So, as you can see `{'id': 'Desk', 'name': 'Will'}` was skipped (was never assigned to `item`) and will not be removed as you expected.

A quick solution is to use a shallow copy of the list for iteration:

```
for item in array2[:]:  #notice the [:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Paulo's answer, but converting to a `set` first within the filter:

```
array2[:] = filter(lambda L, S=set(array1): L['id'] not in S, array2)
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `[:]` here?

Comment: @arshajii so that any other names bound to the instance of the list also "have items removed"